# Opening a .gpg file via emacs under termux

Tags: encryption

I have installed the termux and app and used it to install emacs on my android phone, i.e.

http://endlessparentheses.com/running-emacs-on-android.html

I then installed gpg via termux, i.e.

```
$ apt-get install gnupg2
```

However when I try to open a symmetrically encrypted .gpg file (private key) in emacs (running under termux) I get the following error:

```
Error while decrypting with "/usr/bin/gpg":

gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
gpg: problem with the agent: Not a typewriter
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Its as though it doesn't know that I have to provide the decrypt key via the emacs minibuffer in order to open the file

I've tried various permutations of the following elisp in my .emacs file:

```
(require 'epa)
(epa-file-enable)
(setq epg-gpg-program "/usr/bin/gpg"))
;; Don't display graphic prompt in terminal
(when (not (display-graphic-p))
(setq epg-gpg-program "/usr/bin/gpg"))
```

but all to no avail thus far

anyone with any pointers/experience in this area gratefully received..

Comment: Does `(setq epa-pinentry-mode 'loopback)` help?

Answer (score 1):

> Error while decrypting with "/usr/bin/gpg":

On Termux there is no `/usr` folder, so you need `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/gpg` (or perhaps you can just specify `gpg` without full path?).

Also, note that you should use `gpg2` if you want to use `gnupg2` - the `gpg` program is from gnupg version 1 (and would require `apt install gnupg`).

Comment: hmm - good spot. I've tried and can run gpg and gpg2 from the termux cmd line. So they're obviously on the PATH. I modified the .emacs file location as you suggested, just using gpg2 rather than /usr/bin/gpg2. Still coming back with same error though..curious